# How to send the faster response before the code execution using PHP

Tags: php

I need to send the response before executing some part of the code using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
            $description=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['description']);
            $date=date('m/d/Y H:i:s A');
            $sql=mysqli_query($connect,'INSERT INTO db_feedback (name,email,mobile,description,date_added) values ("'.$name.'","'.$email.'","'.$mobile.'","'.$description.'","'.$date.'")');
            if ($sql) {
                $result=array("msg"=>"Thank You !! Your feedback is sucessfully submitted.","status"=>1);
                echo json_encode($result);
                $email='info@thespesh.com';
                $name='Admin';
                $msgSub="User Feedback";
                $message=$description;
                $uname=$name;
                $uphone=$mobile;
                $uemail=$email;
                ob_start();
                include "feedbackTemplate.php";
                $msg_body=ob_get_clean();
                $is_send=sendMail($email,'noreply@thespesh.com',$msgSub,$msg_body);
            }else{
                $result=array("msg"=>"Failed","status"=>0);
                echo json_encode($result);
            }
```

Here I am sending the email after inserting user data into database. I need before executing the email code part the `echo json_encode($result);` will send the response to the user and after the email part will execute.

Comment: Are you using `php-fpm` or are you using (the worst possible) `mod_php` and Apache? I'm asking because to achieve what you want, you need to change execution model - email should be sent after the response has been sent, and whatever you do with output buffer functions - it won't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running `php-fpm`, which you should, since it's 2018. and all popular web servers support it, then you can use [fastcgi_finish_request](http://php.net/fastcgi_finish_request) function

What does it do for you? You do your database insert, you send a response to the user, call `fastcgi_finish_requets`, output is sent to user and after that function invoke your mailing code.

Long running task is executed after user receives the response.

Code:

```
echo json_encode($result);

// Output is sent to user, but below code resumes execution
fastcgi_finish_request(); 

// This basically resumes in background
include "feedbackTemplate.php";
$msg_body=ob_get_clean();                

$is_send=sendMail($email,'noreply@thespesh.com',$msgSub,$msg_body);
```

**Note: this is only available when you run PHP using** `php-fpm`.

Answer (score 0):

Safest way is to put the task "send this email to that person" into database, and then fire a script from crontab to process those tasks. Script could be scheduled to run for example every 5 minutes. But be aware so it will not take more than 5 minutes to process tasks, so it won't be running more than one at the same time. I usually restricted the count of tasks processed at one script run and use `timeout` shell command to kill the script if it took too much time.

Nowadays I use Redis or RabbitMQ and forking workers. Lookup "php background tasks" in Google and check [php-enqueue](https://enqueue.forma-pro.com/).